# AFNetworking 2 POST Memory Leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, resource-leak

I used AFNetwoking but the simple AFHTTPRequestOperationManager's         `POST:parameters:success:failure` got a memory leak:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST:@"https://my.url.com"   
   parameters:@{@"key":@"value"}
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
      {
         NSLog(@"Sent!");
      } 
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
      {
         NSLog(@"failed!");
      }];
```

Here are the relevant screenshots:

[image]

Expanded - CFURLCredential:
[image]

Expanded - NSCFString
[image]

I'm using `ARC`. I have a method & inside that method is the request above. 
It is automatically called when the view controller appears -- `viewDidAppear`.

Every time the method is called the memory leak happens. I thought it was the dictionary (not the example above) that I am passing so I removed my dictionary parameter and changed to a simple `@{"key":@"value"}` just to be safe. Then, the leak happened again.

Before, I encountered a memory leak because the method was being called in the background, so I tried to put a button and link that to an `IBAction` to ensure that the method is triggered properly:

```
- (IBAction)sendRequest:(id)sender
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

   [manager POST:@"https://my.url.com"   
      parameters:@{@"key":@"value"}
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
         {
            NSLog(@"Sent!");
         } 
         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
         {
            NSLog(@"failed!");
        }];
}
```

Still, every time I press the button and the request finishes, the leak always occurs.

By the way, I'm testing it on an iPhone4 iOS 7.

Comment: The above code is unlikely to leak on its own

Comment: Where do you see this leak - in instruments? As David said: unlikely that here is the cause...

Comment: Yes @rokjarc, in instrument.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question at the moment. Probably you should add instruments screenshot and explain your thought process that led you to conclusion that leak originates from this part of code.